# Buttons not lining up correctly

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, layout-manager

My buttons aren't lining up correctly... whats wrong?

```
private void loadPuzzleButtons()
{
    if (active_puzzle != null)
    {
        int devider = 5;
        int count = 0;
        JToggleButton puzzleButton[] = new JToggleButton[active_puzzle.getNumberOfPieces()];
        for(int row = 0; row < active_puzzle.getRows(); row++)
        {
            for(int column = 0; column < active_puzzle.getColumns(); column++)
            {
                puzzleButton[count] = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon( active_puzzle.getPieces()[count].getPieceImage() ) );
                puzzleButton[count].setLocation(200 + active_puzzle.getPieceWidth() * column + devider * column,
                                                200 + active_puzzle.getPieceHeight() * row + devider * row);
                puzzleButton[count].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                puzzleButton[count].setBorderPainted(false);
                puzzleButton[count].setBorder(null);
                mainPuzzlerPanel.add(puzzleButton[count]);
                mainPuzzlerPanel.validate();
                count++;
            }
        }
        mainPuzzlerPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Here is a photo of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0YiN.png

[image]

Sorry I'd give you my whole code but its larger and well I'm not going to do that...

Thank you in advance, do ask if you need more info!

I figured it out to those who wan't to see how I solved the problem.

```
private void loadPuzzleButtons()
{
    if (active_puzzle != null)
    {
        int count = 0;
        GridLayout puzzleLayout = new GridLayout(active_puzzle.getRows(),active_puzzle.getColumns(),3,3);
        puzzlePanel.setLayout(puzzleLayout);
        JToggleButton puzzleButton[] = new JToggleButton[active_puzzle.getNumberOfPieces()];
        for(int row = 0; row < active_puzzle.getRows(); row++)
        {
            for(int column = 0; column < active_puzzle.getColumns(); column++)
            {
                puzzleButton[count] = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon(active_puzzle.getPieces()[count].getPieceImage()));
                puzzleButton[count].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                puzzleButton[count].setBorderPainted(false);
                puzzleButton[count].setBorder(null);
                puzzlePanel.add(puzzleButton[count]);
                puzzlePanel.validate();
                count++;
            }
        }
        puzzlePanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of alingment are you looking for.  there ARE all in horizontal alignment

Comment: I'm lining them up like you would a grid of boxes, except these change in size and quantity, so the layout can't be fixed.

Comment: @user2925592, you should use `revalidate()` not validate() and you only need to do it once after you have added the components to the panel. So the revalidate() should be just before the repaint().

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to fill panel properly

Comment: e.i. job for Gridayout

Answer (score 0):

what do .getcolumns and getrows output.  try it. output the column and row inside the inner loop and make sure you get at least those numbers right.  are you sure row ever increments?